# Hololens 2 emulator for openxr hello_xr test

Tags: hololens-emulator, openxr

I am working on Windows 10 with Windows Mixed Reality Runtime and Hololens 2 emulator to run the [hello_xr](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenXR-SDK-Source/tree/main/src/tests/hello_xr) test . I was able to build the project using Visual Studio 19 and run it from command prompt as follows

```
hello_xr.exe -g D3D12 -ff Hmd -vc Stereo -bm Opaque -s Local
```

This is unable to get system and throws the following error although Hololens 2 emulator has been launched prior to running the above command

```
[16:09:52.495][Info   ] Press any key to shutdown...
[16:09:52.586][Info   ] Available Layers: (0)
[16:09:52.616][Info   ] Instance RuntimeName=Windows Mixed Reality Runtime RuntimeVersion=112.2211.2002
[16:09:52.623][Error  ] XrResult failure [XR_ERROR_FORM_FACTOR_UNAVAILABLE]
    Origin: xrGetSystem(m_instance, &systemInfo, &m_systemId)
    Source: ..\..\..\src\tests\hello_xr\openxr_program.cpp:298
```

Maybe I should launch the test from within Visual Studio using Hololens 2 emulator as debug target for this to work. But I am not sure how that can be achieved.

How do I go about debugging this? I just started with XR development.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved in the [Khronos forums](https://community.khronos.org/t/hololens-2-emulator-for-hello-xr-test/109433?u=wdfsj).

Update (adding some context in case the link is unavailable later):
Instead of hololens emulator we can also use Windows Mixed Reality Portal or SteamVR to run the hello_xr sample. I used SteamVR along with an android phone. Steps followed were

1. [Install SteamVR](https://www.vrwiki.cs.brown.edu/vr-hardware/hardware-emulators/ivry-tutorial) (Updated the link).
2. Change the active runtime from Windows Mixed Reality to SteamVR. The path to the [manifest json file for SteamVR](https://steamcommunity.com/app/250820/discussions/8/2448217320134491995/) should be `{drive}:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\SteamVR\steamxr_win64.json` . Registry editor can be updated to change the active runtime, details about runtime discovery can be found in the [loader spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenXR/specs/1.0/loader.html#runtime-discovery).

Comment: first link gives : 404. That’s an error.